# AngularJS. Контроллеры и сервисы в функциях, вызываемых на месте

Tags: javascript, angularjs

По каким причина элементы Angular оформляют в функциях, вызываемых на месте?

Вот пример:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('AvengersCtrl', AvengersCtrl);

    AvengersCtrl.$inject = ['dataservice'];

    function AvengersCtrl(dataservice) {
        var vm = this;

    ...
)()
```

Зачем?

```
(function (){})()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае код других контролеров и сервисов в вашем приложении не должен знать о `AvengersCtrl`, пока не будет внедрен через `$inject` в этот другой контроллер или сервис.

Это ограничивает область видимости переменных, что позволяет не беспокоится о именовании переменных и функций в каждом файле, ведет к более чистому коду с использованием [внедрения зависимостей](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) — это, в свою очередь, позволяет тестировать контроллер или сервис, полагаясь только на те переменные и функции, что определенны в коде этого файла или внедрены в него.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.